# C program taking standard input

Tags: c

So i have made a program that takes words and sorts them alphabetically. Instead of the input being standard input, my input is being sent in via command line which i don't want that. I am having issues on how it approach it.

to run my program with inputs i have to type
`./a.out Orange Apple banana`

but i would like to be able to type `./a.out` then press enter and then type in my input.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i, j, k, size;
  size = argc -1;
  char *key;
  char* a[argc-1];


  for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    key = argv[i];
    key[0] = tolower(key[0]);
    j = i-1;
    while (j >= 1 && strcmp(argv[j], key) > 0) {
      argv[j+1] = argv[j];
      j--;
    }

    argv[j+1] = key;
  }



  if (argc > 1){
      for (i = 1; i < argc;){
        puts(argv[i]);

        while (argv[++i] != NULL && strcmp(argv[i - 1], argv[i] ) == 0)
          continue;
      }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: So you typed code in which it does completely what you don't want it to do? Look into scanf?

Comment: why dont you use scanf ?

Comment: This is the only way i know of how it would take as many inputs as it can, with scanf how would i go on about adding strings in. @OmidCompSCI

Comment: @AkashMahapatra ^

Comment: How many inputs do you want to have? If you don't know make some loop like a do-while and ask the user do you want to enter something else "y" or "n" and continue the loop with a scanf

Comment: char continue; do { printf("Enter string: "); scanf("%s", myCharArray); printf("Continue (Y/N)"); scanf("%c", &continue) }while(continue == 'Y');

Comment: And if you don't want it to overwrite each time, just concatenate it, look into strcat.

Answer (score 0):

When you start program you can give it some data over terminal (like you are doing in your example) or you can explicitly ask user to give you some data via scanf() function.

For your example you could use something like:

```
int main() {
    // You need to allocate space for something that you will read.
    char input[100];
    // You need to know how many things you want to read.
    while(something)
        scanf("%s", input)
}
```

Downside of that is that you need to know in front how long your word is gona be and how many words you will have so you can save them in some array if you want to sort them or do with them for something else (or use c++ with list or vector or set or something else for saving and string for saving words, set will sort words for you ;) ).

Comment: well I am not supposed to know how many input words are going to be in. thats my issues.

Comment: If this is a programming assignment, I suspect that you missed or slept through the class where the professor discussed how character arrays work, how to manage memory, etc.

Comment: You can use some word like "end" to finish reading input, but for your problem I think is better to give data via terminal at program start

Comment: @DavidHoelzer you are right. My russian professor is boring and fell asleep. You got that one right.